# making web browser

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using java to create a web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064732/using-java-to-create-a-web-browser)

Is there any way to make a webbrower using java?.
if yes pls give the idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can make a webbrowser by using java.

You would have to parse the html content of the pages you request.

If you're not interested in creating your own browser, here is a link how to [display simple html files.](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.text/ep_ShowHTML.html)