# Web Browser in JAVA

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using java to create a web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064732/using-java-to-create-a-web-browser)

Hello, I am last year computer science student wanted to create web browser 
same as google chrome or as epic browser. Is it possible to create it in java

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible - [here's](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) the proof.

Comment: Haha, I posted the exact same example!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. [Here](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) is an example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all the required libraries are there to support your effort (Java2D/Swing for the rendering, SAX/DOM for the XML parsing, ...).

This is not a simple task however, and creating a fully compliant browser (one that would pass all ACID tests, for instance) from scratch could take you at least a couple of weeks, full time.

Comment: A couple of weeks?  I'd say it'd require longer than that.  More on the order of months, but then I'm conservative.  Hope it's not an "end of semester" project.

Comment: I think "a couple of weeks, full time" was supposed to be a joke. I would estimate the effort at multiple years to get to ACID passing levels, although you can probably build a retro browser with support for HTML 1.0 in maybe a few months.