# D3js within Java application

Tags: java, javascript, swing, web, d3.js

What is the best way to embed a [D3js visualization](http://d3js.org/) within a Java application?

Initial thoughts:

- [JWebPane](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/waiting_for_jwebpane) (Vaporware)
- [Lobo browser](http://www.lobobrowser.org/)  (Still at HTML 4 and CSS 2)
- [DJ Native Swing Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/news/index.html) (Inactive since 2011)
- Other ideas?

There have been related SO questions ([such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064732/using-java-to-create-a-web-browser/3065667#3065667)), I'm looking for solutions specific to supporting D3js.

I am open to ideas that may not include a full blown web-browser integration, just the minimal set required for D3 visualization.  I'm thinking this would include a Javascript interpreter, DOM manipulation, and an HTML/CSS layout engine such as WebKit.

Comment: `Desktop@browse()`? It's not embedded, but it leverages an valuable user preference.

Comment: Embedded is a strong requirement for me at this point, but thanks for the info.

Comment: Sounds like a bad combination: Javascript in Swing. I would rather look for an equivalent/analog library which actually targets Swing. Otherwise, you can always have a look at [JavaFX browser component](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) which supports HTML 5, JS, SVG and CSS3. Haven't tried,but according to its doc, your JS lib should work on it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SWT's browser component via SWT/AWT [bridge](https://gist.github.com/r10r/2305091)

Answer (score 1):

I have used JavaFX and webengine for this. But I am really thinkig about porting d3 to Java ...

Comment: Here is a description on bidirectional communication between JavaFx WebEngine and JavaScript: https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx

Answer (score 1):

[javafx-d3](https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/javafx-d3) - Provides a Java API to use the JavaScript library d3.js with the JavaFx WebView.

So far this seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon [this d3js](https://github.com/gwtd3/gwt-d3-js) without testing it.

Answer (score 0):

the best way i have seen till now that importing jxBrowser library and call your html...or what ever extension was to java application. Later, you play with the Jfram change the size you want and etc..