# making a browser without using JTextPane or any other class that reads HTML

Tags: java, jeditorpane

Good evening, I'm working on a project with a team, we have to make a browser without using JEditorPane or any other class that reads HTML.
How can we do that? Do we need to make a new class that does what JEditorPane does? Can I find somewhere JEditorPane's code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is an answer:

If you need to display web content without using any pre-existing engine (such JEditorPanel or a ChromeBind), you need to read the HTML as a XML file and construct your native View based on it (without CSS and JS this is a fairly easy task) by constructing the screen based on a one-to-one equivalent of a HTML tag to a Java JComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Web Browsers are pretty complicated, so there are a lot of different pieces that come together to display a web page. In order to build a browser, you need to first understand what a browser is. For that, I recommend reading [this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/).

Once you have an understanding of how a browser actually works you need to determine which pieces you can reuse and which pieces you have to write from scratch. Do you have to write the entire rendering engine? Good luck! Can you use an existing engine like [Gecko or Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653949/embeding-gecko-webkit-in-java)? Or maybe you can get a little closer to done and use the [java port of Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064732/using-java-to-create-a-web-browser)?

Once you have a better understanding of the question come back and ask more direct questions when you get stuck at a specific piece. As it is, your first step is to gain an understanding of the problem you are trying to solve.